# CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MySql' could not be found

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

how i can fix this problem??
help me

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MySql' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
Line 1:  using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

Comment: Did you try doing what the error message says? What happened?

Comment: To quote Flippi on a similar post: "Solved this issue! Turns out the newest MySql.Data.dll is built off of .Net Framework 4.5.2, while my project was using .Net Framework 3.5 Client Profile." Change the framework and that should fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if this is not the case but working on the assumption that you're developing in a version of Visual Studio,  check the project references.

If MySql.Data exists in the references but has the warning (yellow triangle) indicator next to it then you may need to re-reference the .dll from its location in your filesystem.

Alternatively, you can grab this from the Nuget package manager if it is not available locally.

Despite the full namespace qualification, the library must be correctly referenced for the object namespace to be recognised in the IDE.

Let us know what IDE you're using if not VS.